# Netbeans JUnit automated testcases

Tags: netbeans, junit

I am writing some unit tests in Java using NetBeans for a big project university java project, but it's boring to write these by hand.  Is there a tool that can help me automate the creation of these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Projects view, right click on the class. One of the last popup menu entries is tools and there you find a wizard to generate JUnit or TestNG classes.

This generates the boiler plate code for you. The test logic itself comes from you.

Maybe you could start here https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html.